# Start psql with read-only transactions by default

Tags: postgresql, transactions, psql

My goal is to start the psql client with read-only transactions as the default.  I can get this behaviour my manually setting [`default_transaction_read_only`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DEFAULT-TRANSACTION-READ-ONLY) once psql has started (e.g. `SET default_transaction_read_only TO on`), but I don't want to have to do that.

Theoretically this seems like it should work:

```
psql --set=default_transaction_read_only=on mydb myuser
```

But it doesn't, probably due to the caveat mentioned [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html):

> These assignments are done during a very early stage of start-up, so
>   variables reserved for internal purposes might get overwritten later.

Is there a way to do this, ideally with a single command line invocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably with [`ALTER ROLE ... SET ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterrole.html), or could put that in your [".psqlrc"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN88543).

Comment: Ah, .psqlrc seems to work.  Thanks for that.  I was hoping to not have to reference a separate file, but if nothing better surfaces here, I'll go with this.